# Trig substitution of $\sqrt{x^2-9}/x$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

$$
   \int {\sqrt{(x^2-9)} \over x} dx
$$
I used $ x=3\sec u $ for the substitution.

I simplified it down to $ {\sqrt{(x^2-9)}-3\operatorname{arcsec}{x \over 3}}+c $ However, wolfram alpha simplifies my answer to

$$ {\sqrt{(x^2-9)}+3\arctan\bigg({3 \over {\sqrt{(x^2-9)}}}}\bigg)+c $$

Overall the integral was pretty simple but i cannot figure out how or why it was simplified to that ansewr. All I know is that it has something to do with domain or range.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha's result is hardly a simplification.

Comment: Would you have left it as is?

Comment: Yes that's what I meant, because the expression inside your $\operatorname{arcsec}$ is much less complicated than what's inside the $\arctan$.

Answer (score 0):

If $t$ is such that $\cos(t)=\frac{3}{x}$, i.e. $t=\text{arcsec}(\frac{x}{3})$, then $\tan(t)=\frac{3}{\sqrt{x^2-9}}$.

The minus in front can be explained by a difference by an additive constant $\pi$ (two angles that leave the same tangent).

Comment: for tan(t) I got the reciprocal of what you put

Answer (score 0):

$$- \operatorname{arcsec}\left({\frac x 3}\right) = \nu$$

$$-3 \sec \nu = x$$

$$9 \sec^2 \nu = x^2$$

$$9 \sec^2 \nu -9  = 9 \tan^2 \nu = x^2 -9$$

$$\tan \nu = -\frac{\sqrt{x^2 - 9}}3$$

We take the negative square root to end up with the same sign as the original.

The flipping Wolfram Alpha does, for whatever reason, comes from the constant of integration, and the following identities:

$$\arctan x + \operatorname{arccot}x = \pm \dfrac \pi 2 $$

$$\arctan x = \operatorname{arccot} \frac 1 x$$

Of course, there's nothing wrong with $-\operatorname{arcsec}\left({\dfrac x 3 }\right)$; I'd say that the computer's simplification isn't a simplification at all.

Comment: Sure thing! I had to really think about what the computer was doing. If you like my answer, feel free to accept it!